# Rails link_to with remote: true not requesting JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to render a modal to update a task but when using remote: true with link_to it just requests html format, I've even checked the request headers which also do not accept js.

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong. I've tried stating the format in the link_to and having a respond_to in the controller but that renders a raw text html rather than executing the js in my .js.haml

Offending code:

View [.html.haml]:

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task), remote: true
```

Controller:

```
  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    render :show_form
  end
```

show_form.js.haml:

```
:plain
  $('#modal1').modal('open');
  $('#modal1').html("#{escape_javascript(render partial: 'create_task', locals: {task: @task})});
```

Also I have all the required libaries included, I even use remote: true else where in the code to submit forms and it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes per per below code in your controller.

```
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html { render layout: 'YOUR LAYOUT' } 
     format.js
  end

you can use template or text in place of layout.
```

Comment: It still only looks for html format and when I specify my .js.haml it says layout missing still. If I specify that the format should be js then it renders the js.haml but then just displays the source and doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Write the below in your manifest file `(application.js)`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: right click & view page source , paste your html page source here