# Render partial on a link_to without refreshing view on Ruby On Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'd like to render a partial on a button click without refreshing my page.

I tried doing this in my `exploitation_controller`:

```
def show_content
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end
end
```

In `routes.rb`:

```
get '/exploitation/show_content', to: 'exploitation#show_content', as: 'show_content'`
```

`<%= link_to "Show", show_content_path, :remote => true %>` in my master view.

Then I have `$('#div_id').html("<%= render :partial => 'my_partial' %>");` in `exploitation/show_content.js.erb`

It gives me the following error : `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you update your question with some example of this, it will make it a lot easier for people to come up with a solution - you might not be far off :)

Comment: I tried to do like explained in answer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174798/render-partial-on-click

Comment: Are you confused to where to put `<%= link_to "Show", show_function_path, :remote => true %>` ?

Comment: I'm confused where to put the `js.erb` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're unsure where to put `delete_content.js.erb`.

If this is the case (assuming your controller name is `functions`, as your question suggests), you'll need to put it in `app/views/functions/delete_content.js.erb`. Then your code should work as anticipated, and as in the answer you've linked in your comments.

So, in the controller:

```
def delete_content
  respond_to do |format|               
    format.js
  end        
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to "Show", show_function_path, :remote => true %>

<div id = "div_id"></div>
```

However, as it stands, unless you're doing something unconventional in `routes.rb`, that link is to hit the controller's `show` action. You'll need to define a new route for `delete_contents`, such as the following:

**routes.rb**

```
get '/functions/delete_contents', to: 'functions#delete_contents', as: 'delete_function_contents'
```

And update your link to:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Contents", delete_function_contents_path, :remote => true %>
```

And in `app/views/functions/delete_content.js.erb`:

```
$('#div_id').html("<%= render :partial => 'my_partial' %>");
```

Hope that helps, let me know how you get on!

Comment: @MaxPuissant - did this help at all? Seems like it should be the right approach following your most recent comment on the question... let me know how you get on and if you have any questions.

Comment: I have the following error when I click on the `link_to`button : `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Comment: Huh - that suggests your controller is receiving a request for a format other than `js`, which `remote: true` is meant to ask for. Could you try debugging by adding `puts request.format` (or using something like [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails)) and letting me know the output please?

Comment: Actually, another quick question: did you update your link to point to the `delete_function_contents_path`?

Comment: `puts request.format` in my `show_content` function gives me `text/html`

Comment: Yes, I updated the link to point to the correct root

Comment: Strange, that should work - for older versions of Rails (not sure about v5) there are a couple of JS dependencies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433770/rails-link-to-with-remote-true-not-requesting-js#answer-45435582). Otherwise there's a good read [here that might help](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4211-Using-Ajax-and-jQuery-in-Rails-5-Apps). I'd suggest you post your updated question as a new question as it covers a different issue - give me a shout there if you want me to take a look. And if you think this has helped get you in the right direction, give it a tick :)

Comment: Thank you @srack, I will take a look on your link

Comment: I've tried this both methods, and everytime the best I can do is to render my partial in a new page, and without bootstrap

Comment: That is very unusual - I'd genuinely recommend setting up a new question with your latest code. You've found where everything should be and it appears correctly setup, so people will be able to give advice based on _why_ the new setup might fail.

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted this way : 
I put `display: none` on every div containing my partials by default. Then on click I change display to block. It works

Comment: Glad you got it working - one thing to bear in mind using that approach is whether there's anything rendered on the page (albeit hidden) that contains something you don't want the user to see. Any nefarious folks could access this via the console. All the best with it!